# Command-line to execute Acrobat Action Wizard action from VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I've built an action in Action Wizard in Adobe Acrobat Pro 11 and named it say "myAcrobatAction".
I want to use it automatically in Outlook using VBA code.

Is there a way to call the user defined Acrobat action through the command-line or other way so I will be able to insert the command in VBA code to execute it from an Outlook/Excel etc. application?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I also need an answer to this, one can hope for an answer one day.